# How to replace while with do-while in this code?

Tags: c#, do-while

Is there any easy way to add "do" to this program? Need to have one "do" in my assignment :)

```
namespace Uppgift_1___Gissa_talet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random randomerare = new Random();
            int slump_tal = randomerare.Next(1, 101);

            Console.WriteLine("Minigame: Gissa talet!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett tal mellan 1 och 100:");

            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int tal = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            while (tal != slump_tal)
            {
                if (tal < slump_tal) //Är det mindre?
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fel! Större!");//Säg då att det ska vara större
                }
                else if (tal > slump_tal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fel! Mindre!");
                }
                tal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Läs in nästa gissning

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Grattis! Du gissade rätt!");
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck på en tangent för att avsluta...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this, C++?

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to `do`?  You should [edit] your question to clearly outline what you are trying to accomplish, and what part of the provided code this question applies to.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Looks like C# by the capitalization.

Comment: This is C#. Is it possible to show how many guesses have been done with a "do" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Uppgift_1___Gissa_talet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Random randomerare = new Random();
        int slump_tal = randomerare.Next(1, 101);

        Console.WriteLine("Minigame: Gissa talet!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett tal mellan 1 och 100:");

        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int tal = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        do //You start the loop before the test expression is checked
        {
            if (tal < slump_tal) //Är det mindre?
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel! Större!");//Säg då att det ska vara större
            }
            else if (tal > slump_tal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel! Mindre!");
            }
            tal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Läs in nästa gissning

        }while(tal != slump_tal); // The test expression is checked here.

        Console.WriteLine("Grattis! Du gissade rätt!");
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck på en tangent för att avsluta...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: Why has the condition changed in the while statement?

Comment: Appreciate the help! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm testing it out right now and I always guess the correct number on like the 2-4th try, is something wrong? Seems weird^^ edit: Nevermind, works great now with }while(tal != slump_tal);

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is move the `while` to the end of the block (followed by a semi-colon) and add a `do` to the beginning of the block.

Additionally, this allows you to move the user input completely inside the loop instead of having it written twice. The only catch is that `tal` must be defined outside the loop since it's used in the `while` condition:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int slump_tal = new Random().Next(1, 101);
    int tal;

    Console.WriteLine("Minigame: Gissa talet!\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett tal mellan 1 och 100:");

    do
    {
        tal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (tal < slump_tal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fel! Större!");
        }
        else if (tal > slump_tal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fel! Mindre!");
        }
    } while (tal != slump_tal);

    Console.WriteLine("Grattis! Du gissade rätt!");
    Console.WriteLine("Tryck på en tangent för att avsluta...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

---

Another improvement you could make is to include a helper method that validates that the user input is actually a number, so that you don't throw an exception if they enter something like "two" instead of "2". The following method takes in a "prompt" string (the question for the user), and makes use of a loop where the condition uses [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to validate that the entry is an integer, and it continues to loop until it returns `true`, then returns the integer entered by the user:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}
```

Now we can make use of this method to get the user input:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int slump_tal = new Random().Next(1, 101);
    int tal;
    var prompt = "Skriv in ett tal mellan 1 och 100: ";

    Console.WriteLine("Minigame: Gissa talet!\n");

    do
    {
        tal = GetIntFromUser(prompt);

        prompt = tal < slump_tal
            ? "Fel! Det numret är för litet. Försök igen: "
            : "Fel! Det numret är för stort. Försök igen: ";
    } while (tal != slump_tal);

    Console.WriteLine("Grattis! Du gissade rätt!");
    Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att avsluta...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```